# Count values and create new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df
    Daily Risk Score
0   13.0
1   10.0
2   25.0
3   7.0
4   18.0
... ...
672 14.0
673 9.0
674 15.0
675 6.0
676 13.0
```

I want to count the number of times a value of 0<x<9, 9<x<17 and >=17 occurs. I tried doing this:

```
df1=pd.cut(df['Daily Risk Score'], bins=[0, 9, 17, np.inf], labels=['Green','Orange','Red'])
```

However, all this does is change the value to the label. What I want is a new dataframe that just has the counts of the values like this:

```
df1
Green   Orange   Red
x   y   z
```

What am I missing to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.groupby` and `.transpose` at the end of this code.

```
df1 = pd.cut(df['Daily Risk Score'],
             bins=[0, 9, 17, np.inf],
             labels=['Green','Orange','Red']).reset_index(). \
             groupby('Daily Risk Score').count().transpose()
df1
```

output:

```
 Daily Risk Score   Green   Orange  Red
 index              3       4       2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df1=df.groupby(pd.cut(df['Daily Risk Score'], bins=[0, 9, 17, np.inf], labels=['Green','Orange','Red'])).size()
```

**df1:**

```
          Daily Risk Score
Green     3
Orange    5
Red       2
dtype: int64
```

#### OR

```
df1=df.groupby(pd.cut(df['Daily Risk Score'], bins=[0, 9, 17, np.inf], labels=['Green','Orange','Red'])).size()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1.reset_index().values.T)
df2.columns = df2.iloc[0]
df2 = df2[1:]
```

---

**df2:**

```
    Green   Orange  Red
1   3       5       2
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with a bit different method. Its easy too. Try it out and let me know if you face any issue/error.
Here you go:

```
df["col"] = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
    if 0<df["Daily Risk Score"][i]<9:
        df["col"][i] = "0<Daily Risk Score<9"
    elif 9<df["Daily Risk Score"][i]<17:
        df["col"][i] = "9<Daily Risk Score<17"
    elif 9<df["Daily Risk Score"][i]<17:
        df["col"][i] = "Daily Risk Score>=17"
    else:
        df["col"][i] = "other"
df["col"].value_counts()
df.drop(columns=["col"])
```